# Backbonejs: model fetch means model not "refreshed"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on a project with Backbonejs (1.0.0) and I'm trying to fetch a model. Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but fetching a model means getting data from server and update model attributes. So, what I did:

The model:

```
var Lead = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute     : "project_id",
    defaults: {
        ws_qs       : 'toto'
    }
});
```

The action:

```
/* this.model comes from a collection, which has been fetched earlier. 
   So this.model contains correct data. I just want to refresh from the server. */
var tmpModel = this.model;
this.model.set({ws_qs : "youpi"}, {silent:true});

this.model.fetch({
  success : function (model) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Fetch generates an XHR call with a correct url.

Some idea: in Chrome debuger, the XHR call response is empty, but opening xhr call url in a browser display correct JSON.

6 hours spending on that bug... anyone could help me?
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a small sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hey! I think that will be too complex :( There are many views, and collections involved... If you can provide me some "tracks" to look for that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Chrome debugger shows an empty response to the XHR, that's a strong indication that the server is misbehaving. Do you have access to the server side code? Perhaps the server code is looking at the request headers and responding incorrectly when the `X-Requested-With` header is `XMLHttpRequest`?

Try this command line `curl -v  -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" <url>` and see what the response headers and body look like.

Comment: Ok, so a good test would be doing a jQuery Ajax call on the url (without backbon)?

Comment: Well, in fact chrome said response is empty when I add a breakpoint on "// do something"... until the end of the script... so maybe a Chrome "feature"... and my collection.fetch works on the same server.

Comment: model.fetch IS a jquery ajax call, so no, that's not a good test. See the curl command I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe something wrong on the server side. check the response setting, if you want got json response, content-type should be "application/json". and it was "text/html" or something else in your case.